# PHP INSERT It Show only one

Tags: php, sql

```
<table border="1" width="500">
 <tbody>
<tr>
 <th>ProFileID</th>
<th>CogID</th>
<th>FileValue</th>
  <th> Count </th>
 <?php
    $sql="Select * From idtable"; // Read idtable
  $result=mysql_query($sql); //  Query sql
$num=mysql_num_rows($result); // Check  record 
 if($num>0){ // If record > 0
 $count=1; // 
 while($recordset=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ // loop 
?>
 <tr>
<td align="center"><?php echo $count; ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $cogid = $recordset['CogID']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $FileValue = $recordset['FileValue']; ?></td>
 <td><? $url = "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/cloudpoc2/".$cogid."/Contacts/contactsversion3/".$FileValue."";
 //example "https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/cloudpoc2/us-east-1%3Ab9b09e99-5921-494a-b5a7-54f289131eaa/Contacts/contactsversion3/Contacts_1437450598237.txt";
 $getText = file_get_contents("$url", true);
$Contact = substr_count($getText ,"FIRSTNAME");
 echo   $countupdate   =   $Contact; ?>
</tr>
 <?
  $count+=1; // Increase count +1
 }
}
 ?>
</tbody>
<?php   // UPDATE TO DATABASE
$updatecount = "INSERT INTO counttable (ProfileID,Count,Timestamp)
VALUES('','$countupdate','')";
mysql_query($updatecount);
?>
```

**I want to update count to phpmyadmin *Table name is Countable* I have 2 data but it show only one data  i don't know what happen  ** Some on kind please help me

This my pic

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do an update **after** `while` loop is over. After loop is over `$updatecount` stores the last value of `$Contact`. If you want to update table on each iteration of `while` loop, move your update query in the loop:

```
while($recordset=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { // loop 
    // do something here

    $updatecount = "INSERT INTO counttable (ProfileID,Count,Timestamp) VALUES('','$countupdate','')";
    mysql_query($updatecount);
}
```

Comment: Oh Thank you sir  That so simple , Thank you so much @u_mulder